# Carrierwave cannot save file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

Carrierwave keeps returning the error below when i tried to save a remote url.

```
photo = space.photos.build        
photo.remote_image_url = photo_url
photo.save!          
# NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was just an old version of the fog gem, version `0.9.0`. To solve the problem just add this to your gemfile:

```
gem 'fog', '>= 1.11.1'
```